# Is it possible to changed grouped character individually (regular expressions sublime )

Tags: regex, notepad++, sublimetext3

so in regular expressions i group stuff like
 `Find: (text1|text2)`
is it possible to group them both and replace them like

`Find: (text1|text2)`
i want to replace the **text1** with **hello1** and **text2** with **hello2**
without need to replace the word individually every time like :

```
find: text1
replace: hello1
_________________
find: text2
replace: hello2
```

sorry about the bad English
i dont know what to search for or what the keywords are i'd love if tell me how or link me a article and i can go from there

thank you

Comment: No, it is not possible because the replacement patterns there do not support conditional constructs. You can do that in Notepad++ though.

Comment: Yes Thank You - I Tried It Just Now And It Didn't Work (: ( In Notepad++)